# How to clear values filled in the input by JS using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So for the sake of learning, I am trying to automate the search process in Expedia.com
my code selects "bundle deals", then "flight+Hotel+Car" then starts entering values. (depending on your location, you might see different sets of panels)

The problem is, I'm trying to automate the departure and arrival date by selecting them and inserting a date in mm/dd/yyyy format. Everything goes perfectly until it tries to input the date in returning date. It inputs the date, and then JS changes the date back, and my test fails.

```
public void selectDepartingDate(String date)
 {
     WebElement dte= driver.findElement(departDate);
     dte.sendKeys(date);


 }

 public void selectReturningDate(String date)
 {
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     WebElement dte= driver.findElement(arrivalDate);

     dte.sendKeys(date);


 }
```

How exactly can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to click and clear it before sendKeys:

```
public void selectReturningDate(String date)
{
    WebElement dte= driver.findElement(arrivalDate);
    det.click();
    dte.clear();
    dte.sendKeys(date);
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? When i tried it, it cleared, added the date i wanted to add, but when the script moved on, the date reverted back to the date coming from js. So the test still fails.

Comment: @gasmsk yes, I've tried and it works well. Could you remove the implicit wait and try again?

Comment: I did, still reverts back to the js date when the script moves forward. What should i do?

Comment: @gasmsk Can you show me the variable `arrivalDate` and the `date`?

Comment: By arrivalDate= By.id("package-returning"); 
String departDate= "09/15/2016";
String arrivalDate="09/31/2016";
and JS keeps changing it to "9/15/2016"

Comment: @gasmsk ok, I can replicate your problem now. The arrivalDate is incorrect. It should be "09/30/2016".

Comment: omg.... *dies*
I have no words. Do you think its best practice to key the dates in or should i work the calendar instead? Could you guide me with that?

Comment: @gasmsk If you want to test search, you should key the date because the calendar element is complex. If you want to test the calendar, use the calendar.